# How do I vendorize gems for Rails3/Bundler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, bundler

In Rails 2.X, I could simply copy gems into `vendor/gems/gem_name`, or use the rake command `rake gems:unpack`. Since Rails3 uses bundler, it doesn't appear to work anymore. I have found the command `bundle package`, but it doesn't work the same way.

### Edit:

So, just to elaborate a bit on this:

The way that rails 2 worked, I could easily *grep* to find stuff in `vendor/gems`. If they are bundled up in `.gem` files, that isn't possible. Also, when developing a gem/plugin, it's very helpful to have it placed within a rails application to test it out in context. How would I do such things with bundler/rails3? Is my workflow inherently broken somehow?

Comment: I have a rails 2 application, in that already I have mysql2 gem inside vendor folder. My doubt is, in case of Rails 3 we can call the gems inside the vendor folder in Gemfile like,


          `gem 'gemname', :path => 'path to gemfile inside vendor directory'`


But I don't know where and how to call the gems in vendor folder in Rails 2. Can anyone please help me in this. How to require and mention the path of the gem that present inside the vendor folder(as we dont have the Gemfile)?

Answer (score 113, accepted):

Answering the second part of your question, developing a plugin/gem and shipping it with the rails app without making the gem publicly available, you may do this

Gemfile

```
gem 'my_private_gem', :path => "vendor/gems/my_private_gem-VERSION"
```

assuming you performed a `gem unpack my_private_gem --target vendor/gems`

note: *bundle package* unpacks all gems (as many as in Gemfile.lock). I wouldn't want those in git.

Comment: Just a note to add that if you have used the "gem unpack" command then you will need to explicitly list the version number of the gem you have vendored, as there will be no *.gemspec file -  see the [manpage](http://gembundler.com/man/gemfile.5.html)

Comment: I had to include the gem version number for bundler to find the gem in the given path.

gem 'my_private_gem', '1.2.3', :path => "vendor/gems/my_private_gem-VERSION"

Comment: The my_private_gem-VERSION approach to unpacking didn't work for me, but this did: gem unpack my_private_gem --version VERSION --target vendor/gems

Comment: This worked for me `gem unpack my_private_gem --target vendor/gems --spec` but it put the gem spec in the current directory not the target! so then `mv my_private_gem.gemspec vendor/gems` now bundler won't complain about the gem version.

Answer (score 27):

The Bundler equivalent *is* `bundle package`. It packages all of the .gem files specified in the Gemfile into `vendor/cache` so that future installs get the gems from this cache rather than from http://rubygems.org/

Comment: Thanks for reassuring me that this *is* expected behavior. It doesn't really solve my root problem though, so I have accepted Ole's answer instead.

Answer (score 23):

The correct Bundler equivalent is `bundle install --deployment`. This will install the gems, in their unpacked state, in `vendor/bundle`.

Comment: Thanks. This seems to be equivalent to `rake gems:unpack`. For my use case, I just want to vendorize a single gem, so here Ole's answer is still the best solution, but it's good to know that there is a better way, if you want to vendorize all gems.

Comment: This answer and comments are important to the question because many people seek to 'vendorize' most-but-not-all gems

Answer (score 6):

This is what worked for me:

```
gem unpack <GEM_NAME> [-v <VERSION>] --target vendor/gems
gem specification <GEM_NAME> [-v <VERSION>] --ruby > vendor/gems/<GEM_NAME>[-<VERSION>].gemspec
```

For example:

```
gem unpack sidekiq-pro -v 2.1.4 --target vendor/gems
gem specification sidekiq-pro -v 2.1.4 --ruby > vendor/gems/sidekiq-pro-2.1.4.gemspec
```

The first command unpacks the gem into the vendor/gems directory.  However, that doesn't contain the gemspec.  The second command creates the associated gemspec.  It's noteworthy that another poster mentioned something similar.  This solution correctly writes the gemspec in ruby format instead of in yaml.

You can then update your Gemfile to point to the vendored gem:

```
gem '<GEM_NAME>', '<VERSION>', :path => "vendor/gems/<GEM_NAME>-<VERSION>"
```

For example:

```
gem 'sidekiq-pro', '2.1.4', :path => "vendor/gems/sidekiq-pro-2.1.4"
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using "hosted" development infrastructure delivered by the [hosted_gem_development](https://github.com/dadooda/hosted_gem_development) gem.

> Developing gems is often tricky because they act like separate projects with regard to the applications you use them in.
>
> "Hosted" development infrastructure makes gem development easier by including them into (making them "hosted by") your live application. Then you update your gem's code like you update regular application code.

[Go to project page](https://github.com/dadooda/hosted_gem_development)

Comment: It's nice you downvoted me guys, but this post isn't a blind promotion. It is related to gem vendorization, too.

Comment: Say I have a versioned app and I want to always use the latest commit of a gem. Would your gem work (and in production as well)?

Comment: @lulalala, with `hosted_gem_development` you'll have to manually update gem source, e.g. by issuing a `git pull` or whatever.