# Rails 3.1 private gems installation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a private gem, I added to my gemfile

gem 'saml-response', '0.0.0', :path =>"#{File.expand_path(**FILE**)}/../vendor/gems/"

Then bundle install it, and the bundle gets installed in:

```
DANIELs-MacBook-Air:Authy-Google-SSO dani$ bundle show saml-response
 /Users/dani/Development/authy/Authy-Google-SSO/vendor/gems
```

But rails 3.1 seems not no load any gems from vendor/gems

```
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :001 > require 'saml-response'
LoadError: no such file to load -- saml-response
```

So if vendor/gems are not loaded why is bundler installing the gem there.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I vendorize gems for Rails3/Bundler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646847/how-do-i-vendorize-gems-for-rails3-bundler)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why the path magic?

Simply:

```
gem "yourgem", :path => "vendor/gems/yourgem"
```

will work, and yeah, it will load from there.

It appears to be your path.  You're pointing to your *gems directory* but you need to point to directory of *the gem itself*.

```
# not
:path => "vendor/gems"

# but rather
:path => "vendor/gems/saml-response"
```

Comment: nop I am using rails console, really rails is not trying to load from there

Comment: it appears to be the path you're trying.  You don't want to point to the directory where you keep your gems, you want to point to the directory of the gem itself.  I.e. `:path => 'vendor/gems/saml-response'`