# Using bundler to compile gems hosted on github?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler

So, many people like to fork gems and add features to them etc.. that is fine. but it makes trying their gem a bit of work if you have to clone teh gem yourself, download it, install, etc.

I'd like to be able to have bundler compile the gem for me if there is no pkg/gem_name.gem file

This is what I'm doing currently:

```
gem "yard-rest-plugin", :git => "git://github.com/ql/yard-rest-plugin.git"
```

And then the `bundle update` error:

```
Could not find gem 'yard-rest-plugin (>= 0) ruby' in git://github.com/ql/yard-rest-plugin.git (at master).
Source does not contain any versions of 'yard-rest-plugin (>= 0) ruby'
```

Hence why it would be nice if it auto-compiled.

Comment: Maybe is it convention naming problem... For info, here is what I user to include paperclip successfully : `gem 'paperclip', :git => 'git://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip.git'
`

Comment: yeah, the gem is actually called yard-rest, but auto-compiling would be amazing. o.o

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the name of the gem is *gem 'yard-rest'* so this should work:

```
gem "yard-rest", :git => "git://github.com/ql/yard-rest-plugin.git"
```

https://github.com/ql/yard-rest-plugin

Comment: aye, silly that I missed that for this particular case. But what about have bundler compile gems?

Comment: Not compiling in the pure sense, but bundler can package your gems for you -- `bundle install --deployment` will install into `vendor/bundle`. Several options discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646847/how-do-i-vendorize-gems-for-rails3-bundler or http://gembundler.com/bundle_install.html

Comment: not quite the same =\, cause the issue is when I want to use a gem from a git repo that doesn't have a compiled version of the gem hosted.

Comment: still not sure what you mean by 'compiled' in this sense

Comment: create the .gem file from the github source without storing the github source files on your computer. =D

Comment: ah right ok. I do not think bundler could automate. you'd have to fork, and `gem build mygem.gemspec`

Comment: yeah, that's what I don't want to have to do =(

Comment: When you install a .gem that is what happens anyway (extracting files from the .gem into your gems directory). If you wish to distribute the gems, use ``bundle package`` which packages gems into your project's vendor/cache directory.