# Ruby tool to browse through installed gems code

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I am using a gem and I have trouble figuring out how to use a specific method.

Currently to understand how it works, I have to go to github, search the gem realise the code is from a dependency, search the code repo for the other gem, realise it's another gem, locate it, find the class, and from there go from one class to another with a lot of browsers tabs open.

I am on Linux using sublime text. Is there some tool that would allow me to directly access the code from a gem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [pry](https://github.com/pry/pry) with [source-browsing.](https://github.com/pry/pry/wiki/Source-browsing)

It's a console similar to IRB, and you can view the definition of any class/method that is written in plain Ruby.

Here's an example with `rgeo` gem :

```
> pry                                                                                                               
[1] pry(main)> require 'rgeo'
=> true
[2] pry(main)> show-source RGeo::Cartesian.factory

From: ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rgeo-0.6.0/lib/rgeo/cartesian/interface.rb @ line 27:
Owner: #<Class:RGeo::Cartesian>
Visibility: public
Number of lines: 7

def preferred_factory(opts_ = {})
  if ::RGeo::Geos.supported?
    ::RGeo::Geos.factory(opts_)
  else
    simple_factory(opts_)
  end
end
```

Comment: yep, that's what I use

Answer (score 0):

You could "vendorize" your gems, that is instead having them installed somewhere else on your system they are within your project. That way your editor has access the the source code more easily.

If you are using bundler you can do something like `bundle package` which will put your gems in `./vendor/cache`. Reference: [How do I vendorize gems for Rails3/Bundler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646847/how-do-i-vendorize-gems-for-rails3-bundler)

Another way, which I use, is [gem_home](https://github.com/postmodern/gem_home) this will manage your `$GEM_HOME`, which is where gems are installed. You would do something like:

```
cd ~/dev/my_project
gem_home .
bundle install
```

You will then find all your gems in `~/dev/my_project/.gems`.

Which ever method you use don't forget to exclude the directory from version control, e.g. add to `.gitignore`.

Comment: I think the problem is not finding gem's source code. The problem is to determine _which gem it is_ and go to its code directly. What `show-source` does.